# prevent [R] data frames with long lines from being truncated?

Tags: r, dataframe, printing, output

I have data frames that have wide rows, either because they have a lot of columns of numerical values or because they have long text columns

I typically use RStudio and Rmd Notebooks. I can not figure out how to get the entire line printed without a truncation. I get the same behavior when I run the code in the RStudio console so I do not think it is an R markdown issue.

I also want to use capture.out() to save the formatted output from functions like anova. The capture.out() file is also truncated

Here is an example from the RStudio console

```
> fdf <- mcols(res.lfcShrink)
> fdf
DataFrame with 4 rows and 2 columns
                       type            description
                <character>            <character>
baseMean       intermediate mean of normalized c..
log2FoldChange      results log2 fold change (MA..
lfcSE               results posterior SD: diseas..
svalue              results FSOS s-value (T=1): ..

> mcols(res.lfcShrink)$description
[1] "mean of normalized counts for all samples"           
[2] "log2 fold change (MAP): diseaseState PDAC vs healthy"
[3] "posterior SD: diseaseState PDAC vs healthy"          
[4] "FSOS s-value (T=1): diseaseState PDAC vs healthy"
```

I tried setting "limit length of lines displayed in console to" 500. Did not help

thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: (1) That isn't a vanilla R data.frame, it might be similar or just a super-class of it. It has some similarities to `tbl_df` from `tibble` and `dplyr` fame, but it looks different enough. Also, what is `mcols`? What non-base packages are you using? (2) Do you mean `capture.output()`?

Comment: I'm inferring that you are using Bioconductor's [`S4Vectors`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/S4Vectors.html) package. On a cursory look, I can find no mention of "console width" (or similar) in [any](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/S4Vectors/inst/doc/S4QuickOverview.pdf) .. [of their](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/S4Vectors/inst/doc/S4VectorsOverview.pdf) .. [docs](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/S4Vectors/man/S4Vectors.pdf), nor in its [github repo](https://github.com/Bioconductor/S4Vectors).

Comment: Would printing `as.data.frame(fdf)` produce non-truncated output?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for us to verify this? Also include any non base package used.